# Data Encoding in C and Python

Tags: python, c, encoding

I'm encountering the following question. I've written some double-type data into binary files using C and now I want to read them using Python. When I used python function

```
with open("test.dat","rb") as dfile:
    data = dfile.read()
```

It gave me

> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11@'

So I tried to decode using `data.decode()`, then it gave me decoding error. I suppose it was because I used the wrong encoding type. But I tried `ascii` and `utf-8` and they did not work. Therefore my questions is 2-fold:

1. How can i read an binary file without knowing the encoding type?
2. Since i did not give an encoding type when writing the binary file in c, does c encode the data at all? If yes, what kind of encoding type would that be?

FYI, the code i used to write binary file in the first place is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  double buffer[4]= {1.5, 2.5, 3.25, 4.25};
  FILE *ptr;

  ptr = fopen("test.dat", "wb");
  fwrite(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,ptr);
  printf("%ld\n",sizeof(buffer));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "decoding" in this sense is to convert binary data into text. However, the data you saved in your C program represents double-precision floating point numbers, not text.

Comment: You need to convert the C types into Python types.  Use `struct.unpack` in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: Aside, in C the buffer size printed should be with `printf("%zu\n",sizeof(buffer));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the C types into Python types. Use `struct.unpack` in the standard library [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

The format string, in this case, is `dddd`, meaning 4 doubles.  The difficulty comes when moving C types between different compilers and machines.

```
import struct

with open('test.dat', 'rb') as dfile:
    data = dfile.read()

result = struct.unpack("dddd", data)
print(result)
```

Gives a tuple:

```
(1.5, 2.5, 3.25, 4.25)
```

Comment: This assumes the same endianness (which tends to be a feature of the hardware).  If you look at the documentation you will find that endianness can be specified, https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings in 7.1.2.1. Byte Order, Size, and Alignment

Comment: That's why I said in my post *The difficulty comes when moving C types between different compilers and machines*.  As you know, for example, `sizeof(int)` is not specified in the language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python standard [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module:

```
from array import array

u = array('d')

with open('test.dat', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    u.frombytes(data)
    print(u)
    print(u.tolist())
```

Output:

```
array('d', [1.5, 2.5, 3.25, 4.25])
[1.5, 2.5, 3.25, 4.25]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using numpy, use [`np.fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html):

```
with open("test.dat","rb") as dfile:
    data = np.fromfile(dfile)
```

You may find numpy arrays easier to manipulate than plain python types because of the huge ecosystem of code that's grown up around them.